# Elasticsearch 1.7 installation marvel-agent failed

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I have installed ElasticSearch 1.7 and want to install marvel, bellow command to install licence worked.

```
sudo bin/plugin --install mobz/elasticsearch-head --verbose
```

But installing marvel itself failed:

```
vagrant@homestead:/usr/share/elasticsearch$ sudo bin/plugin install marvel-agent
-> Installing marvel-agent...
Trying https://github.com/null/marvel-agent/archive/master.zip...
Failed to install marvel-agent, reason: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information
```

How to solve this ?
with `--verbose` this occurred `vagrant@homestead:/usr/share/elasticsearch$ sudo bin/plugin install marvel-agent --verbose
-> Installing marvel-agent...
Trying https://github.com/null/marvel-agent/archive/master.zip...
Failed: IOException[Can't get https://github.com/null/marvel-agent/archive/master.zip to /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/marvel-agent.zip]; nested: FileNotFoundException[https://github.com/null/marvel-agent/archive/master.zip]; nested: FileNotFoundException[https://github.com/null/marvel-agent/archive/master.zip]; 
Failed to install marvel-agent, reason: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information`

Comment: Try `--verbose` as suggested? The github organization called _null_ seems weird..

Comment: @StephenKing with `--verbose` it fails also.

Comment: No surprise that it also fails ;-)

Comment: Please fix your formatting. You see how I fixed your previous text. Please invest in readability.

Answer (score 2):

For Elasticsearch 1.7, the correct command is different than for 2.x:

```
bin/plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```